# Call Eloquent collection functions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a model relationship between 3 different tables/models.

Since I get a collection of objects due to hasMany-property I have to use a for-loop to access each of the Models methods in order to get the data I want.
Is there anyway to tell that I want it to run the same function on all the objects?

Pseudo code:

```
Model A     //HasMany Model B
Model B     //HasMany Model C, Belongs to A
Model C     //BelongsTo C


$foo = new User::Find(Auth::id());

//Need to loop the collection of data in order to get the information
foreach($foo->permissions as $permission)
{
    $name = $permission->permissionsTypes->name;
}
```

I have tried to do this:

```
$foo->permissions->permissionsTypes;
```

But since it is a collection it does not work.

Is there any other way to get this information without looping through the array?

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: are you sure in all $foo->permissions has permissionsTypes ? If any permission does not have then it will not work

Comment: Yes, but I get an error that the property does not exists on the collection instance. So if I create a for-loop then I can call the function on each of the objects one by one fine.

Comment: What is relation you have defined between permission andPermission types. is hasOne or hasMany

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want all `permissionsTypes` in one collection?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, that was the goal. But it seems that I have to loop through each item one by one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pluck()` and `collapse()`:

```php
$permissionsTypes = $foo->permissions->pluck('permissionsTypes')->collapse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be you have defined the hasMany relationship if yes then please change hasMany into hasOne then

```
foreach($foo->permissions as $permission)
{
    $name = $permission->permissionsTypes->name;
}
```

Or you could just get one of objects by it's index:

```
{{ $permission[0]->name}}
```

Or get first object from collection:

```
{{ $permission->first() }}
```

When you're using `find()` or `first()` you get an **object**, so you can get properties with simple:

```
{{ $object->name}}
```